# Higher level file read/write with Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, file-processing

As Objective-C is superset of C, I guess I can use `fopen/fread/fwrite/fprint...` just like I do with C.

Does that mean that Objective-C doesn't have its unique file processing function?

Comment: Does this link help out? http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/199087-file-processing-with-obj-cocoa.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objective-C doesn't have file handling, nor does C. However, the C Standard Library does. And if you want to use Objective-C, you can use the C Standard Library.

Objective-C is mostly used with Foundation, so `-[NSData writeToURL:atomically:]` and `-[NSString writeToURL:atomically:encoding:error:]` can be used if you link to the Foundation framework.

For reading files the methods are `-[NSData initWithContentsOfURL:options:error:]` and
`-[NSString initWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:]`.

Comment: +1: People do tend to forget Objective-C is framework independent.

Comment: You might wanna add NSFileHandle to your answer as well, since it's more analogous to the stdio functions the OP asked about.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `NSFileManager` and `NSFileHandle` classes for a start. Many other classes, such as `NSData`, also have methods to read data from a file and write data to a file.

Answer (score 0):

initWithContentsOfFile:error:

initWithContentsOfURL:error:

writeToFile:atomically:

writeToURL:atomically:

and so on, NSData NSString NSImage and so on all support these methods